# How to correctly pass argument to final 'if' conditional when column formatting using JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Based on the example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#conditional-formatting-based-on-the-value-in-a-text-or-choice-field-advanced), I am using the following JSON to add icons next to column values, depending on their value:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style":
            {
                "display": "inline-block",
                "padding": "0 10px 0 0"
            },
            "attributes":
            {
                "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Value 01', 'TextDocument', if(@currentField == 'Value 02', 'FileImage', if(@currentField == 'Value 03', 'MSNVideos', if(@currentField == 'Value 04', 'Website', 'Website'))))"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is an anomaly with the last `if` conditional, whereby there are two arguments, i.e.:

```
if(@currentField == 'Value 04', 'Website', 'Website')
```

Whereas, in order to look like the other `if` conditionals, there should be just one, i.e.:

```
if(@currentField == 'Value 04', 'Website')
```

However, when I remove that second argument, and use the code directly above this sentence, the desired formatting is not applied (no icons are shown at all).

Why does the final `if` conditional seemingly need two arguments?

*Note that the original example provided at the beginning of this question also has two arguments for the last conditional.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` expression requires 3 arguments:

- Condition
- TRUE result
- FALSE result

When you are nesting `if` expressions you are providing the nested `if` expression as the FALSE result. Generally, the final FALSE result is the default result (when nothing else matches use this). So, with your nested conditions the last `if` is unnecessary and can just be replaced with the default value.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style":
            {
                "display": "inline-block",
                "padding": "0 10px 0 0"
            },
            "attributes":
            {
                "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Value 01', 'TextDocument', if(@currentField == 'Value 02', 'FileImage', if(@currentField == 'Value 03', 'MSNVideos', 'Website')))"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expressions are written on a single line which makes them hard to follow when you've got anything but a simple expression. The `iconName` expression is easier to understand if broken across lines:

```
=if(@currentField == 'Value 01',
    'TextDocument',
    if(@currentField == 'Value 02',
        'FileImage',
        if(@currentField == 'Value 03',
            'MSNVideos',
            'Website'
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see above every `if` expression has 3 arguments. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style":
            {
                "display": "inline-block",
                "padding": "0 10px 0 0"
            },
            "attributes":
            {
                "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Value 01', 'TextDocument', if(@currentField == 'Value 02', 'FileImage', if(@currentField == 'Value 03', 'MSNVideos', if(@currentField == 'Value 04', 'Website', ''))))"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you try this? Is it working for you??